# High-quality PDF becomes pixelated when opened in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, georeferencing, pdf

I am currently working with a high-quality PDF file that displays perfectly when viewed in Adobe. However, when I import this file into QGIS for georeferencing, the quality significantly degrades and the image becomes pixelated.

I've tried various settings within QGIS to improve the image quality, but so far, I haven't had any success. I'm wondering if there might be a workaround within QGIS that I'm not aware of that might handle this type of high-quality PDF better for georeferencing purposes.

How can I maintain the original quality of the PDF when importing it for georeferencing in a GIS application?

*Original file screenshot when opened in Adobe*

[image]

*Screenshot of the same area after importing to QGIS for Georeferencing:*

[image]

**EDIT:** After converting to TIFF format with DPI set to a higher value

[image: After converting to TIFF with DPI set to a higher value]

Comment: Could you share some test data?

Comment: Asking for software opinions in GIS SE is asking to get your Question closed for being *opinion-based*. I suggest you [Edit] this to focus on the problem, not on alternative approaches.

Comment: @Vince I've deleted the question about opinion

Comment: It looks bad because your PDF is being loaded as a raster, you could try to get the vector data using a PDF-DXF (eg https://cloudconvert.com/pdf-to-dxf) or PDF-SHP (eg https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/pdf-to-shp) then georeference the vector. Disclaimer: I have never used nor specifically endorse these services, they are only provided as examples of services that exist.

Comment: @user30184 Sure here is one sample file for testing https://www.adur-worthing.gov.uk/media/Media,156286,smxx.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since QGIS uses GDAL to load PDF files, we could set an Windows/Linux/iOS environment variable **GDAL-PDF-DPI=300** to increase the raster quality from 150dpi (default) to 300dpi.

Comment: I have tried your solution. But for some reason it was not working i.e, PDF is not loading into the georeferencer. 

So I have used your idea and converted the PDF into TIFF format by using the below command.

`set GDAL_PDF_DPI=1200

gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "PREDICTOR=2" -co "ZLEVEL=9" Media_156286_smxx.pdf output.tif`

I then imported the TIFF file for georeferencing. It worked out pretty well this way.

Comment: @Abhilash I'm glad I could help. Would add `--config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co TILED=YES` to the command line to speed up translation and for image tiling. If your PDF has layers included, you could even remove the unnecessary ones. See all options here: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/pdf.html

Comment: @Abhilash when I look at the sample PDF you have posted, it would be better to use JPEG compression for smaller size and faster loading: `gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES -co JPEG_QUALITY=90 -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 <source.pdf> <target.tif>`. And use overviews: `gdaladdo --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR --config GDAL_TIFF_INTERNAL_MASK YES -r cubicspline <source.tif> 2 4 8 16`